# Linker and complitation in C

Tags: c

I just read a paragraph about linker and complitation in C so i this is what I understood from it : compiler in c/c++ turns the file instead of .c/.cpp (except checking if the code is valid lets assume that the code is valid) to .o/.obj which inside of it the code is written in machine code(binary) and when you run the code it does linking and it takes the object file which was created from the original .c / .cpp and  turns it into and executable file that the machine can read ?

can you plz tell me if that is truth ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file

Comment: About 10 seconds of google-fu [served up this](https://calleerlandsson.com/the-four-stages-of-compiling-a-c-program/), and it probably answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth but somewhat simplistic.

The compiler generates object code from source code - it compiles a single *translation unit*.  The object code comprises of certainly machine code, but it is not directly executable since it contains unresolved symbols to library code and to code from other separately compiled translation units.  Thes symbolic links are calls or references to code and data whose address is not yet resolved.

The linker brings together multiple object code modules from compiled translation units and from library code (such as the standard library, operating system API etc.), and resolves unresolved symbols(i.e. links everything together). In an OS hosted environment, the linker also adds information required by the OS to load the executable.

Answer (score 0):

When a program is compiled , one or more object files are created which are essentially machine code (0,1). 
These files are the ingredients of your ultimate executable but in raw form.
So when linking (this is just a general idea) these files will be connected and included to make a perfect exe that can be run separately.

> However if error occurs while linking it might mean that some of your
>   function is not defined (or there are multiple defintions) in the file
>   that you've included in your code!